# How to comment multi-line bash script command

Tags: bash-scripting

Is there a way to comment out a multi-line bash command, without commenting out each line with a preceding `#`? when a single command is composed of several lines continued via a slash that is.

Comment: Is this just to save some typing of #'s, or why? Some text editors / IDE's (Geany) can comment & uncomment lots of lines at once

Comment: Yes, it's also for that, if your IDE doesn't support it, for sane debug workflows

Answer (score 2):

I put those lines inside a function that is  never called.

Answer (score 2):

see Michael Rusch's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash)

```
if false; then

...

fi
```

or see further [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947897/block-comments-in-a-shell-script) question.